# when i import the model from my database, i want the instance to my database not to be generated in the database model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new in ASP.net core

With this command I import the model from my database:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost; Database=prueba2; Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

my database is called `prueba2` and the respective models are created in the `Models` folder. The file `prueba2Context` is created where the database configuration is.
In `prueba2Context` the connection to the database appears.

```
    /*protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
         #warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost; Database=prueba2; Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }*/
```

I comment on this code because I have seen tutorials where the connection is configured in the `Startup.cs` file, specifically I use this code inside `Startup.cs` to configure the database:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

      // ******In this line I config the use of my sql server database****
      services.AddDbContext<prueba2Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
      services.AddControllers();
    }
```

then in my controllers I inject the use of the database in the style:

```
    private readonly prueba2Context context;

    public MyControllerDataController(ILogger<MyControllerData> logger, prueba2Context context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

and so I can use my database in the style:

```
context.anyTable.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

if I use the command again to import the model from my database, all the files are created again. and therefore the lines that previously commented will be uncommented. My idea is to have my database instance in `startup.cs` as I indicated. How can I make when the database model is created the instance to the database in `prueba2Context` does not appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the command Scaffold-DbContext is meant to be used the first time you import a Database, and after that, any changes should be updated in the code using Migrations:

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database

Anyway, if you want to keep using Scaffold-DbContext, I think you can keep the OnConfiguring method of the DbContext uncommented, as it is checking the IsConfigured property of the optionsBuilder object, and this property it's supposed to be set to true when you configure the connection in the Startup class:

[What are expected results when optionsBuilder is defined in both DbContext.OnConfiguring and AspCore Startup.ConfigureServices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561771/what-are-expected-results-when-optionsbuilder-is-defined-in-both-dbcontext-oncon)

Comment: Thank you very much, regarding the second, the connection to my database is still showing in the OnConfiguring method of the DbContext   and for safety I would not like it to appear.   but as I understand you, the `scaffold` command should only be used the first time I create my database, and then I must do migrations so that it does not overwrite my entire model.

Comment: That's it, and if you're concerned about hiding your connection string when using Scaffold-DbContext command, you can use a ConnectionString that's set up in your project configuration file if you use this command: 
Scaffold-DbContext "name=<name-of-the-key-of-your-connection-string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext

for example:
Scaffold-DbContext "name=DefaultConnection" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Comment: will it work in my case that I have this configuration? https://i.imgur.com/JK9NO3Y.jpg

Comment: I think so! :)  at least it's as it is said in the docs. Did you try it?